# Is anything wrong with my basic user authentication approach?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, session, authentication

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to security and authentication and most other client-server communication stuff. What I'm trying to do is simple, and if possible, avoid having to bring in 3rd party frameworks and classes to do the job. (I'm using Google App Engine with Python)

A user logs in to the service once via a mobile application (iOS). Once logged in, the user will make many requests, to get things such as messages, friends, statuses, etc. So each time the app talks to the server, rather than sending that user's email and password to authenticate, we'll send a session id. So far, that was just my understanding of the system.

I've come up with an extremely simple approach, which to me seems like it will work just fine, but being inexperienced I'm probably not seeing many things. What would be wrong with doing this:

1. on device, user types in email/password, the credentials are sent to the server and verified, and once authenticated, a random number is generated. This random number is stored as an IntegerProperty on the User model with the name session_number.
2. the session_number is sent to the user's device and is saved. Now, anytime the user connects to the server for a request, the session_number **along with** the user's integer id number are sent to the server. We get the User entity for that userId, and now we compare the value of user.session_number == incoming_session_number. If they match, we're good, else error.
3. If the user logs out, we clear the session_number from the data store.

The only other question here is how would this be handled when the user is logged in from multiple devices? Should each device store its own session_number?

Comment: "the credentials are sent to the server and verified" -- this is the biggest part, and the one most likely to have security holes. How exactly do you plan on doing this? (Google account login over HTTPS?) Apart from that, your scheme seems OK, though you might want to force users to re-login every once in a while (to mitigate any session hijacking risks). Note that I'm far from a security expert too ;-)

Comment: by verified I just mean if incoming_password == user.password, then verified, else error.

Comment: How do you ensure the credentials are encrypted?

Comment: @Cameron the password is stored in the datastore as a SHA256 hash, and that value is also what is sent through the air waves..

Comment: So, essentially, your passwords are being sent in cleartext, in that: if anyone peeks into your database, they can see exactly what they need to send over the wire to log in. Storing a hashed password, and then sending it as the same string, defeats the protection of using the hashing in the first place. You should use a different encryption, for example: Send a random nonce string (perhaps 32 random characters) from the server; have the client append this to the hash of their password, then hash the results, and send it back; the server then appends the nonce to the stored password to check…

Comment: “avoid having to bring in 3rd party frameworks and classes to do the job.” → This sounds like, “I'd like to avoid using well-tested code that other people have already debugged and maintain for me.” Is there some reason you *need* to re-invent the wheel? … If you are not at least as much of a security expert as the teams who wrote those “3rd party frameworks” — some of whom, by the way, are first-party (Google) — then it's extremely unlikely you'll end up with something particularly robust… I'm not trying to be mean, but re-invented wheels, in my experience, are usually octagonal at best.

Comment: @BRPocock I'm not following..let's say the user selects a password "mypass123". I then compute a secured SHA256 digest hash using a unique salt hash. I then send this string and save that in the server as the user's password. Whenever the user wants to log in, I compute the hash again and send that and compare it against the server hash value. How would anyone be able to know what they need to send if they don't know my salt?

Comment: @mohabitar: There are problems with relying on just hashing as a form of encryption. [Rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) render a simple hashing method completely ineffective. If you _really_ want to be as secure as possible, you'll need to salt your passwords, and also use a different hash function (like bcrypt).

Comment: @BRPocock the reason I say I don't want to bring third party stuff is because if I do, I'll end up not really knowing what's going on. I know it'll work, but I won't understand the meanings behind it, and why it was even necessary in the first place. I'm sure years went into them, but I also want to have first hand experience in understanding why those things were necessary. That's why I made this basic example to see why it wouldn't work, and why third party frameworks were even created in the first place. I want to get my hands dirty first, then I'll play with the frameworks.

Comment: Using a 64 bit integer as your session ID is also asking for trouble. My advice would be to not write your own, but rather to use an established system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from my comment about re-inventing wheels; the major problem I see with this theory is that it's completely subject to Replay attacks.

For example, given a user with ID 99 and a session ID / cookie of "MONKEY-1" — if the user wants to send a request, he must sign it with "from, 99, MONKEY-1" in some fashion. Let's suppose it were something like so:

```
{ FROM: 99, TO: SERVER, COMMAND: GET-NEW-MAIL, SESSION: MONKEY-1 }
```

That's great, if MONKEY-1 is a secret. (Whatever format you like; it might as well be a 4KiB binary chunk of line noise.)

Now, however, we have an eavesdropper, who saw that packet go by… She now sends her own packet. Perhaps she's clever, and spoofed the source-IP address that the real user 99 was using — even if the eavesdropper can't hear your reply, she might still be able to send you a packet. Perhaps that one looks like this:

```
 { FROM: 99, TO: SERVER, COMMAND: DELETE-ALL-MAIL, SESSION: MONKEY-1 }
```

There are numerous ways to prevent this sort of thing, which vary in effectiveness. Wrapping the connection in SSL can help make this extremely difficult (but, by no means, impossible) to do; that's the solution a lot of web sites have fallen back on. A better means is to use a two-way communication for signing things in a way that an interloper can't obtain the secret data, using hashing or public/private key cryptography. For example, let's suppose that we have an exchange like this:

```
{ FROM: SERVER, TO: ??, COMMAND: PLEASE-LOGIN, NONCE: PIGEON }

{ FROM: BILL, TO: SERVER, COMMAND: LOGIN, AUTH: hash ( hash ( password ) . "PIGEON" ) }
```

… where `hash()` represents, say, a SHA-256 sum, and `. "PIGEON"` refers to concatenation;

```
{ FROM: SERVER, TO: BILL, COMMAND: LOGIN-OK, SESSION: hash ( password ) ^ "MONKEY-1" }
```

… where `^` refers to some operation like a bitwise exclusive-or, perhaps.
Then, subsequently, Bill sends requests like this:

```
 { FROM: BILL, TO: SERVER, COMMAND: GET-NEW-MAIL, NONCE: "ARMADILLO", 
   AUTH: hash ( "GET-NEW-MAIL" . #\Newline . "ARMADILLO" . #\Newline . "MONKEY-1" ) }
```

Now, at no time has MONKEY-1 traveled in the clear; and, the AUTH key given on each request is tied to the verb or command used, and a nonce, which should vary on every request, and the server can easily verify its integrity, but an eavesdropper cannot replay the same message again, or change the verb and do something different.

To explain the password problem:

I have a database table, and it contains

```
User: BILL, Password: hash(DOLPHIN)
```

If, on the wire, I receive

```
{ FROM: BILL, PASSWORD: hash(DOLPHIN), COMMAND: GET-ALL-MAIL }
```

… then it's unlikely (but fairly plausible) that an eavesdropper would know that the password is DOLPHIN, but, she doesn't need to know, or to care:

```
 { FROM: BILL, PASSWORD: hash(DOLPHIN), COMMAND: DELETE-ALL-MAIL }
```

You mention salting the password… how would you do that?

```
 User: BILL, PASSWORD: hash( SALT . DOLPHIN )
```

Unless you store the SALT and DOLPHIN separately, there is no easy way for you to get from 
`hash ( SALT . DOLPHIN )` to `hash (DOLPHIN)`. So, either the user has to submit `hash ( SALT . DOLPHIN )` to you (putting a static SALT on the client side) or you have to store the plaintext password again.

The work-around might be to do something like

```
 Database: ( BILL => hash ( SALT . DOLPHIN ) )

 Server sends: ( NONCE )

 Client sends: ( BILL => hash ( NONCE . hash ( SALT . DOLPHIN ) ) )
```

Comment: Note: The above is *not* a fully-functional example … which is why I didn't make it look too much like pseudocode … it misses out on a lot of edge cases and possible attack vectors. I just hope to explain a few of the major problems with the basic “I trust a magic cookie from the client” model.

Comment: I'm not understanding how you're using the nonce. Who generates the nonce? And when I send hash ( hash ( password ) . "PIGEON" ) to the server, how do I verify if this is the correct password? Do I encrypt on client side and decrypt on server side? What value is stored for the user's password?

Comment: And what exactly is meant by this line: `{ FROM: SERVER, TO: ??, COMMAND: PLEASE-LOGIN, NONCE: PIGEON }`

Comment: The nonce is a random value; perhaps a string of many random bytes, which is guaranteed to never be the same twice; the first one here (PIGEON) is generated by the server at pre-login-time (the `TO:??` because the server doesn't know who the user is) — with regards to `h(h(pass).nonce)` — the server knows the h(pass) (but not the pass), so it can take `h(pass)` from the database, append its own nonce, and hash that, then compare this to the string returned by the client.

Comment: Naturally, the nonces should never be English words, just lots of line noise (try `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=512 count=1` for example), I've just used arbitrary strings to make this legible.

Answer (score 4):

One **important** aspect of this kind of security model is how you store passwords (or rather, how you don't store passwords). It's not as simple as it may seem, as there are many dangers if done improperly.

[This article](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#properhashing) covers the basics, and provides a good outline on what to look into. It discusses hashing, rainbow tables, salting, and slow hash functions.

Since you're using App Engine, you'll want to research about cryptographic libraries in Python. [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) and [`hmac`](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html) are two that are part of the standard library, but unfortunately Python's standard library doesn't have any implementation of slow hash functions like `bcrypt` or `pbkdf2`.

Thus, I'd recommend using [`passlib`](http://code.google.com/p/passlib/) for password hashing. I'm using it myself for a project (*work in progress*). Specifically, I decided to use `sha512_crypt` - you can take a [look at the code here](https://github.com/voithos/gae-starter-kit/blob/master/core/utils/crypto.py) (any criticism is welcome).

Apparently, there's also a [JavaScript implementation](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) of PBKDF2 built by Stanford.

Comment: +1 for passlib recommendation however I recommend using a CryptContext so that you can be adaptive and easily add more complex schemes and options over time without re-writing auth code or requiring the upgrade of all old passwords. See here: http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.context-tutorial.html

Comment: I'm trying to digest all this new information and have some questions. First, does it matter where I generate the salt and hash for the password, client or server? I'm more comfortable with Objective-C and already have it set up over there, and that's what I'm doing now. I'm hashing the user's password with a constant salt (which as I've read should be created at run time instead), and sending that hash to be verified. But the server doesn't do anything else but check hash1 == hash2. Am I still missing the point?

Comment: @BryceCutt: Nice! Thanks for the link, I'll definitely take a look at that.

Comment: @mohabitar: Surely the server is both more convenient and more secure. If you were thinking of hashing it in JavaScript, well, browsers can just turn it off, so...

Comment: @voithos with a CryptContext when you add a new scheme as the default all new passwords will be encrypted with the new scheme but old passwords will still work. You can add some code to your login handler that detects that someone's password is stored using an old scheme and re-encrypt and store it so you can progressively upgrade old passwords. As password crackers become faster and more mature this should help us keep up.

Comment: @voithos but in the end, it will only be 1 side that does the hashing right? Why would it be more secure in the server rather than client?

Comment: @mohabitar: You have control of the server - you _don't_ have control of the client. And besides, what would be the point? If you're worried about security during the request, that's a job for SSL/TLS.

Comment: @mohabitar: There _is_ a JavaScript crypto library made by Stanford, but as the article I linked to states, you shouldn't rely on client-side hashing as your entire security model (again, because you have no control over it).

Comment: So then when a user, on the client, creates a password, what do I send over the air? If I don't do the hashing on the client side, what am I sending to the server - the cleartext password?

Comment: @mohabitar: The "actual data" that you are sending can be normal text, yes, **but** it should _not_ be cleartext for any attackers. This is where the magic of public-key cryptography comes in. You must use [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (which is known as HTTPS when used to secure HTTP) to encrypt all communications. A discussion on how this is possible can be found [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6290/how-is-it-possible-that-people-observing-an-https-connection-being-established-w).